# Export pdf from Draw document with transparency

Tags: pdf, libreoffice, libreoffice-draw

I use Libreoffice Draw for drawing block diagrams. I export them automatically on the command line using the following command:

```
soffice --headless --convert-to pdf --outdir figures figures_raw/foo.odg
```

However, this does **not** preserve transparency - the background is always white. How to convert *odg* drawings to pdf but preserver the transparency?

Comment: Good question, but probably this is a [better place](https://ask.libreoffice.org/en/questions/) to ask.

Comment: A PDF by specification does not support transparency to the outside; it merely supports transparency among its inner building blocks but the PDF as a whole is specified to live on a white backdrop.

Answer (score -1):

> However, this does not preserve transparency - the background is always white.

This is so by specification. In the PDF specification, when covering the topic of *transparency*,

> the notion of *current page* is generalized to refer to a transparency group consisting of the entire stack of objects placed on the page, composited with **a backdrop that is pure white and fully opaque**.
>
> *(section 11.2 Overview of Transparency, [ISO 32000-1](http://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/PDF32000_2008.pdf))*

Thus, PDF viewer programs or viewing controls usually will display a PDF with a white, opaque background.

Comment: Here's a post on the OpenOffice forum (https://forum.openoffice.org/en/forum/viewtopic.php?f=11&t=66631&hilit=pdf%20transparent) that shows how to do it in the user interface (I don't think this method will work in headless mode). You can select the objects you want to export, 'Export as PDF, then under 'Range' choose 'Selection'.

Comment: And a conforming pdf viewer will still display the rest of the page in white, won't it?

Comment: I've no idea. In my case I was using pdftk to stamp one page onto another, so the stamp had to have a transparent background, and it does so far as pdftk is concerned. The output is clearly different from the usual method of exporting to PDF. I put my comment here in case anyone else runs across this looking to do something similar.