# importing a PDF with a transparent background into Gimp

Tags: pdf, background, transparent, gimp

I have a PDF with a transparent background (verified by opening it up in Adobe Illustrator).  I can't figure out how to import it into Gimp preserving the transparent background (it comes with a white background).  I know I can go through a bunch of steps to make the white transparent and mask the appropriate areas, but it seems like my ask is a no-brainer.  Is there something I am missing?

Thanks in advance, Chuck

Comment: Cf. the quote from the pdf specification in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32882780/1729265) - by specification the there is nothing like a "PDF with a transparent background", *a backdrop that is pure white and fully opaque* is always assumed. So gimp merely follows the specification when importing the background add white.

Comment: Thanks, mkl.  I didn't realize the PDF spec didn't have background transparency.  Makes sense now...

Comment: Of course one could create a gimp feature request for an "import PDF page objects"; that would circumvent the white-backdrop requirement... ;)

Comment: I'm not sure that would work if there are white areas in the non-background objects, right?  PDFs that are created by Adobe with a transparent background must be doing something custom to indicate a transparent area, right?

Comment: Nothing special. Many, probably most PDFs have a certain amount of transparent area through which you usually see the backdrop, white per definition.

Answer (score 1):

I've had a similar problem but I managed to find a workaround that's handy if you don't need to import a lot of PDFs. 
I simply import the PDF to **Inkscape**, save it as SVG and then open the SVG with GIMP. Or just export it as PNG since GIMP imports it as a bitmap anyway.

Comment: This is by far the simplest method I've come across, I got artifacts or resolution issues otherwise.